# Profile annotation without any identifier

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am looking at a project where I see all the classes defined similar to below. I have used Profile annotation to switch between different envs by using something like this - "@Profile(dev)" etc. However what is the purpose of defining Profile annotation without any identifier?

```
@Profile
@Component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `@org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile`

```
public @interface Profile {

    /**
     * The set of profiles for which the annotated component should be registered.
     */
    String[] value();

}
```

You will notice that there is no default `value` set for the value property. This means the code would not compile and your constellation is wrong. I think that "your" `@Profile` annotated class is a different annotation than the supposed from Spring.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry , did not notice the package name. As you mentioned it is not the spring profile!